# Java Number error

Tags: java

i seen to be having a problem with the line:

```
int xPos = ((x / maxX) * X_AXIS_LENGTH) + X_AXIS_OFFSET; =
```

for testing purposes i have assigned:

```
int x = 10;
int maxX = 52;
```

but when used in this calculation `x / maxX` gives me `0` instead of `0.19`!

http://s12.postimage.org/uawn8b6l9/image.png

Comment: i think X_AXIS_LENGTH and X_AXIS_OFFSET both is zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer division here:

```
x / maxX
```

Integer division will truncate the fractional part.

Cast one of the parameters to floating-point to fix it:

```
(double)x / maxX
```

You might also want to store the whole thing into a `double` instead of `int`:

```
double xPos = (((double)x / maxX) * X_AXIS_LENGTH) + X_AXIS_OFFSET;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the operands for `/` are integers, so it's performing integer arithmetic. Options:

- Use floating point arithmetic:

  ```
  double xPos = (((double) x / maxX) * X_AXIS_LENGTH) + X_AXIS_OFFSET;
  ```
- Multiply *before* the division, and you can still do everything in integer arithmetic, although you'll need to beware of overflow:

  ```
  int xPos = ((x * X_AXIS_LENGTH) / maxX) + X_AXIS_OFFSET;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Integer division did it to you.

If you expect a floating point value, do it this way:

```
double ratio = ((double)x)/maxX;
```

That int type all the way though is a problem.  I'd put more thought into that.  Where do you want to truncate the fractional part?

Answer (score 0):

xPos should be declared as double, not an integer.  Otherwise, the data after the decimal point is truncated.